# What happens to the bullet wound on the shoulder of F.W. Colqhoun in Ravenous?

Tags: plot-explanation, ravenous

I saw 1999's *Ravenous* on TV today. Perhaps they had cut a few scenes. There was a scene where Boyd shoots F.W. Colqhoun and he all bleeding with a wound.

When he shows up as Col. Ives they ask him to show the wound, and it isn't there. How did this happen? It wasn't explained in the movie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained at [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravenous_(1999_film)) that the Wendigo myth, which involves eating human flesh is a **cure** for illness and wounds.

> A temporary commander is assigned to the fort and to Boyd's horror it turns out to be Colqhoun, now cleaned up and calling himself Colonel Ives. The others still refuse to believe that Ives is the killer especially after he bears **no sign of the wounds inflicted on him during the fight at the cave**.
>
> Ives tells Boyd that he used to suffer from tuberculosis but when a Native scout told him the Wendigo myth he "just had to try" by murdering him, eating his flesh and **in the process curing his illness**.
>
> ...
>
> Boyd and Ives inflict grievous wounds on each other. **But they don't die easily due to their recuperative powers**.

Comment: can you also help answer this question Paul? https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84206/during-which-time-did-captain-boyd-eat-mans-flesh-in-ravenous-1999