# During which time did Captain Boyd eat man's flesh in Ravenous (1999)

Tags: plot-explanation, ravenous

I saw this movie in TV today and there were no scenes which showed Captain Boyd eating human flesh.

Which time did this happen and were there any scenes showing this?

Answer (score 2):

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravenous_(1999_film)) explains (again)...

> When the soldiers reach the cave where the party had taken refuge they come to realize that Colqhoun and Ives are one and the same. He had killed and eaten his five companions and is now set on trapping and killing them as well. Colqhoun succeeds in doing this one by one, including Colonel Hart, the fort's commanding officer.
>
> Boyd manages to escape the massacre by jumping off a cliff but breaks his leg in the process. **He hides in a pit next to the body of a fellow soldier. Eventually he eats some of the man's flesh to stay alive.**

and

> Eventually **Boyd gives in and eats a stew made out of the last officer killed** and his wound heals.

Comment: Why was this not shown in the movie?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't? Remember the movie may have been edited for TV.

Comment: oh that should be the case